# Is Windows 10 memory compression used if you have no page file?

Tags: windows-10, memory-management

I am investigating the use of Windows 10 memory compression, to decide what the best way is to 'swap out' memory.

On one hand, I could leave everything to Windows, rely on the page file and compressed memory, but this implies that I have no control over what is exactly swapped out and when.

On the other hand, I could run the system without page file, and reduce memory usage by faster persisting temporary changes to database.  Then I have more control over what to persist and remove from memory.

In the latter case, I could still benefit from memory compression, provided that memory compression is used even if you have no page file.  If that is the case, then memory compression would allow my process to use more memory than what's physically available (during a short moment of course).

So the question is: is Windows 10 memory compression used if the system has no page file?

Comment: It has been a while since I researched this, but if my memory serves me correctly, memory compression was moved up the chain, and does not use the pagefile itself. So Memory -> Memory compression -> page file. As in, it will only use the page file if memory compression can't compress enough to free space. In theory memory compression should therefor continue to work while the pagefile is disabled. I would not recommend disabling the pagefile though. The idea is that the pagefile is used as little as possible anyways, so if it is used, there is need for it.

Comment: IIRC, wouldn't disabling the page file result in lost data if memory consumption exceeds the reserve amount for the OS and integrated graphics [if not using a discrete GPU]?

Comment: @LPChip 1. Memory compression is disabled when there is no pagefile. 2. Pagefile is used even when there is enough free memory. For this reason a system with pagefile is always slower than a system without.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page file needs to be enabled for memory compression to be enabled. I've just verified it on Windows 10 version 1809.

I'm normally running this system with page file turned off, and despite enabling memory compression in MMAgent, checking the SysMain service is running and all prefetch & readyboost settings are enabled in registry, Task manager always says "Memory compression is not enabled" and I've never seen "(Compressed)" memory statistic go above 0 MB in the memory tab in task manager.

After setting up a paging file of 16 MB (minimum allowed size), the tooltip in the Task manager tab now shows the expected "Compressed memory stores an estimated .... of data..." message.

What I've still not verified is how does the size of paging file affect the maximum allowed amount of compressed memory.

*Another related note*:
Prefetch and ReadyBoost can be disabled using regedit. They do not affect the operation of memory compression. However, "SysMain" service (confusingly called readyboost in older Windows versions) *must* be enabled, otherwise  memory compression will not be enabled.